# How to find possible subjects for given verb in everyday object domain

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am asking for tools (possibly in NLTK) or papers that talk about the following:

e.g. Input: Vase(Subject1) put(verb)

Ans I am looking for: flower, water

Is there a tool that can output subjects (objects) that can be associated to this verb? (I was going through VerbNet but didn't find anything)

Comment: It is not natural English to say "Vase put ...". A speaker might say "I put water in the vase" or as a request (to un-mentioned listener) "Put water in the vase". In both cases the vase here would be a referred object and not the subject (compared to "The vase is green" or "The glass vase broke" where the vase is the subject). I don't think that changes the question substantially, but you may want to work on a clearer example

Comment: If you want Subject, Verb, Object for your vase example, you might simply change it to "Vase (subject) contains (verb)" or "Vase (subject) holds (verb)" - but if you really want to parse a request for putting something in a vase, then that would be different

Answer (score 0):

If you want something quick, I think [pattern](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern) is the best tool for the job. It provides a ready-to-use multilingual parser that you can use in the following way:

```
import pattern
from pattern.en import parse
s = 'I put water in the vase'
s = parse(s)
print s
# output = I/PRP/B-NP/O put/VBP/B-VP/O water/NN/B-NP/O in/IN/B-PP/B-PNP the/DT/B-NP/I-PNP vase/NN/I-NP/I-PNP
```

Once you have a string like `output` above, you only need regex parsing to extract every sequence of tokens whose tags match the sequence [B-NP, B-VP, B-NP].

NP stands for "noun phrase" and VP stands for "verb phrase". In English, virtually every sequence consisting of a noun phrase, a verb phrase, and a second noun phrase, all in strict adjacency, is a subject-verb-object sequence, so this should give you what you're looking for.

`pattern`'s parser will also be able to handle some non-strict adjacencies (e.g. intervening adverbs and adjectives between the three phrases in the subject-verb-object sequence).

However, `pattern` is not terribly sophisticated -this will give you some Precision and some Recall, but not terribly high numbers. If you need high-quality parsing, you should try the [Stanford parser's Python implementation](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp) or [spacy](https://spacy.io).

Hope this helps!